# Why PHP array "+" operator is reordering my integer keys and how can avoid this?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm generating a **dummy array** where keys are timestamps and values are zeroes. Start is today (date without time part) and going back for `$days` days in the past:

```
$days  = 10;
$limit = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$start = $limit - (($days - 1) * 86400);

// Dummy array of timestamps and zeroes
$dummy = array_combine(range($start, $limit, 86400), array_fill(0, $days, 0));
var_dump($dummy);

array (size=10)
  1337551200 => int 0
  1337637600 => int 0
  1337724000 => int 0
  1337810400 => int 0
  1337896800 => int 0
  1337983200 => int 0
  1338069600 => int 0
  1338156000 => int 0
  1338242400 => int 0
  1338328800 => int 0 // Today is the last
```

This array is going to be **merged** with another one extracted from a MySQL result set (and its values should override dummy ones):

```
$keys = array_map(function($e) { return strtotime($e['date']); }, $values);
$vals = array_map(function($e) { return intval($e['count']); },   $values);

// Array of real values coming from database
$reals = array_combine($keys, $vals);
var_dump($reals);

array (size=1)
  1338328800 => int 2 // Today
```

Since [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) operates a key reordering (when keys of `integer` type) i switched to `+` array operator, and the resulting array is reordered: new keys come first:

```
var_dump($reals + $dummy);

array (size=10)
  1338328800 => int 2 // Today become the first
  1337551200 => int 0
  1337637600 => int 0
  1337724000 => int 0
  1337810400 => int 0
  1337896800 => int 0
  1337983200 => int 0
  1338069600 => int 0
  1338156000 => int 0
  1338242400 => int 0
```

So **question** is `+` operator put those keys first and how can i solve this without using sort functions, as below:

```
$merged = $reals + $dummy;
ksort($merged);
var_dump($merged);

array (size=10)
  1337551200 => int 0
  1337637600 => int 0
  1337724000 => int 0
  1337810400 => int 0
  1337896800 => int 0
  1337983200 => int 0
  1338069600 => int 0
  1338156000 => int 0
  1338242400 => int 0
  1338328800 => int 2
```

Comment: Note that you can use `array_fill_keys()` instead of `array_combine()` + `array_fill()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `+` (applied to the arrays) appends the data from the right array that is not exists in the left array.

You've used `var_dump($reals + $dummy);` which means: take `$reals` which consists of 1 item (today as the first and the only element) and append everything from `$dummy` that has another keys.

The possible solutions are:

1. sort the data (you mentioned that)
2. merge manually, with `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could use string keys in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` to prevent `array_merge()` from re-indexing. It's also more descriptive than timestamps. You could use `DatePeriod` to easily create the keys.

If you are looking for an optimal solution, I would do something like this:

```
# begin timestamp
$ts = 1337551200;

# values from database
$values = [
  ['date' => '2012-05-23', 'count' => 42],
  ['date' => '2012-05-26', 'count' => 666]
];

# holds the key=>val pairs
$data = [];

foreach ($values as $value)
{
  $value_ts = strtotime($value['date']);

  # backfill all missing dates
  for ($missing_ts = $ts; $missing_ts < $value_ts; $missing_ts += 86400)
    $data[$missing_ts] = 0;

  # add date from database
  $data[$value_ts] = $value['count'];

  $ts = $value_ts + 86400;
}

# append all remaining dates
for ($now = time(); $ts <= $now; $ts += 86400)
  $data[$ts] = 0;
```

This just does one iteration over the data from the database and inserts missing keys with values of 0. It only works if `$values` is already sorted, and it depends on days being exactly 86400 seconds apart (as does your original solution).

It may not be 'copy-paste' ready, but it should give you an idea on how you could implement a one-pass solution with minimal overhead. Functions like `array_map()` are nice to provide very concise code, but if you're really dealing with lots of data, I would expect that this type of solution will be the fasted. (Benchmark to find out.)

Comment: What would this change? `+` would still work the same way, as a `union` of 2 arrays

Comment: But pure int/string manipulation should be faster instead of looping on `DatePeriod` for large values, i'm i right? This should be also memory efficient instead of thousands of object instances...

Comment: @zerkms, this is a workaround to the general problem, not how `+` works. PHP won't nuke string keys on a merge like it does integer keys. @Gremo, nothing in PHP is memory efficient... Anyway, you wouldn't have thousands of object instances, as you would be creating strings out of them. Always benchmark before writing off a potential solution.

Comment: `PHP won't nuke string keys on a merge like it does integer keys` -- could you please show that on example? From my perspective I don't see the difference in this particular case

Comment: @zerkms, compare `array_merge([12 => 'foo'], [13 => 'bar'])` with `array_merge(['012' => 'foo'], ['013' => 'bar'])`. @Gremo, Regarding performance: you don't need to use the date objects to easily build string keys.

Comment: @Matthew: I do know how how `array_merge` works, but OP uses keys and don't want to lose them. Do you have an example of what you want to say in the context of **this particular question**? And I remind you - OP wants the original order, original data (both keys and values) and merging that respects the order. For now your question makes no sense - because there is no difference how to store the data - as a string, or as an integer - `+` works the same for them (and you didn't mention another operator/function in your answer)

Comment: @zerkms, from what I understand, `$merged = array_merge($dummy, $reals)` does exactly what he wants if he is using string keys. This of course assumes that `$reals` does not introduce any new keys. All that said, given that he is performing two maps on the entire `$values` array, I would bet that doing this by hand via `foreach` is the optimal solution in PHP.